# Prevent reset of data in input form after changing server instance

Tags: forms, input, payment

1. I'm trying to design an "add card payment" form with Stripe implementation, the real challenge is that I have two accounts for two regions US & Europe.
2. My current design is that user is presented with Modal on top of it with two radio buttons for changing the regions and under radios the form with payment card info, when user changes the regions, the data in forms is cleared out cause backend has to connect to the account of the other region.
3. Is there a better UX practice for implementing this, so the user doesn't loose payment card data that he has validated after switching the region?

Comment: How much control do you have over the client side scripting and styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better *UX* practice, yes: Implement the form yourself and make this work (binding the same data to different forms is not hard in js).

However, you probably don't want to do that, because as you probably know Stripe solves quite a lot of high-stake problems and edge cases that you really don't want to code yourself.

Here are some other thoughts:

### Possible Solutions (w/o ditching Stripe widget)

- **hack together a script** on top of the widget that saves the form values in LocalStorage and then adds them into the other form. This is fairly elegant UX-wise, but probably a pain in the ass coding-wise because I don't reckon Stripe makes it too easy to mess around with its widgets.
- have a crystal-clear **region-select screen before the user ever sees the payment form**. Save that value somehow (LocalStorage or just with different urls), so switching regions halfway through isn't really a thing anymore.
- **just ignore this** - it reflects well on you that you care about this (and this *is* the UX StackExchange), but in the end, I would think it is fairly rare that users would want to change their region halfway through if you make it in any way clear that they have to pick a region (especially if you have sensible defaults, e.g. by doing a best guess at the users country). There are probably challenges more in need of your attention ;)

Comment: Thank you! Good points.